# dynamic values web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

Hello guys I've been trying to web scrape some pages that contain values that change all the time, but I'm not able to get the prices so far. Can anybody help me, this is where I reached so far!

```
import requests
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

my_url = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com/'
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
options.binary = binary
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:/Users/Genti/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/selenium/geckodriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
browser.get(my_url)
html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

sel_soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')
prices = sel_soup.findAll("td", {"class":"price"})
print(prices)
```

Comment: you want all the 10 prices ?

Comment: yes I would like to get all the prices

Comment: Do you want to get up-to-date values in real-time or just extract 10 prices once?

Comment: I would like to extract all the prices up-to-date but I would like to extract only the price and the name of the currency, nothing more maybe form a table

Comment: lets say the ideal scenario would be for me to get the name of the currency, price, and the date

Comment: I see no date in table... What should be the date? Just today date?

Comment: yes, timestamp maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code to get currency names, prices

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import datetime

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

my_url = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com/'
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
options.binary = binary
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:/Users/Genti/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/selenium/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get(my_url)

names = [name.text.split('\n')[0] for name in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'desktop-name')))]
prices = [price.text for price in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'current-price-value')))]

print(datetime.datetime.now())
for name, price in zip(names, prices):
    print(name + " - " + price)
```

Comment: @antonio when defining names and prices I'm getting an error selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: and I don't get anything in return

Comment: @GentBytyqi , I'm not antonio, but it's OK :)) Can you double-check whether required page is opened? (make a screenshot of page) You might be re-directed to another page

Comment: @Anderson no page is being opened

Comment: @GentBytyqi , did you try it in headless Firefox only? How did you check that correct page is opened?

Comment: previously the page was opened itself automatically, now it is not.

Comment: @GentBytyqi , try now. I just copy-pasted your code and didn't notice that missed `driver.get()` line :) Also for some reason you opens two browser sessions: `browser` and `driver`...

Comment: @anderson, I get the same error from when names and prices are defined for this waiting period, the date is being printed, maybe I can fix it myself, thnx for the answear it helped alot !

Comment: @GentBytyqi , this is weird... I checked in Chrome (not headless) and got both names and prices...

Comment: Can I try it with chrome as well instead of firefox

Comment: @GentBytyqi , you can [download chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/) and use it in non-headless (`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`) or in [headless mode](https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python)

Comment: @anderson it's working I only added the html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") and its working thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you want all the 10 prices. you'd have to store all the prices in a list, like this :

```
all_prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[class='price'] div")
```

then just iterate through a loop to get the values :

```
for price in all_prices:  
  print(price.text)
```

let me know, if you are facing any difficulties.

Comment: I'm facing some difficulty getting an output basically I'm running all the code on command prompt but I'm not getting any result in return

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use BS and not Selenium Webdriver:

```
prices = sel_soup.select("td[class^='price'] > div")
```